# Tree structure: validating depth level of tree

Tags: javascript, php, tree, fancytree

I've build category tree using fancytree. Deepness of each node starting from root have to equal 4 so I may have:

- category

  - subcategory 1

    - subcategory 2

      - subcategory 4
    - subcategory 5

      - subcategory 6

Script should allow to save to database only that kind of structure. I've tried to find some methods related to depth in Fancytree API but I couldn't find proper one.

I decided to write backend validation and I have something like that:

```
        private function validateTree($tree)
        {
            foreach($tree as $node)
            {
                $parentName = $node['title'];
                if(isset($node['children']) and is_array($node['children']))
                {
                    if($this->validateLevel($node['children']) < 4)
                    {
                        $this->errors[] = $parentName;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->errors[] = $parentName;
                }
            }
        }

        private function validateLevel($nodes, &$depth = 2)
        {
            foreach($nodes as $node)
            {
                if(isset($node['children']) and !empty($node['children']) and is_array($node['children']))
                {
                    $this->validateLevel($node['children'], ++$depth);
                }
                else
                {
                    return $depth;
                }
            }

        }
```

This don't work as expected and probably not validating every childs of each root node. Any ideas?

Comment: This line: `$this->errors[] = parentName ` is missing a semicolon.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't really helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like no one can help me (apart from pointing out typo errors) so I figured out it by myself.
It's little bit ugly solution but it works like I want:

```
private function validateTree($tree)
    {
        foreach($tree as $node)
        {
            $parentName = $node['title'];
            if(isset($node['children']) and is_array($node['children']))
            {
                if((bool)$node = $this->validateLevel($node['children']))
                {
                    $this->errors[] = $node;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->errors[] = $node;
            }
        }
    }

    private function validateLevel($nodes)
    {
        foreach($nodes as $node)
        {
            if(isset($node['children']) and (bool)$node['children'] and is_array($node['children']))
            {
                foreach($node['children'] as $nodeLvl3)
                {
                    if(isset($nodeLvl3['children']) and (bool)$nodeLvl3['children'] and is_array($nodeLvl3['children']))
                    {
                        foreach($nodeLvl3['children'] as $nodeLbl)
                        {
                            //everything is OK
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->errors[] = 'Category'.$nodeLvl3['title'].' does not have lvl 4';
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->errors[] = 'Category'.$node['title'].' does not have lvl 3';
            }
        }
    }
```